# How do I say "This is a derivative work. I am in no way affiliated with X company" in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, translation, words, business-japanese

I am not sure which verb would be used for "affiliated" in this context. Would it be 提携して? Or perhaps 関係して?

Comment: Do you want to express that the work has no relations with the original authors?

Comment: The message I'd like to convey is that the speaker was not hired by X company to produce the derivative work, and is not employed at that company. :)

Comment: 「〇〇はフィクションであり、実在の△△とは一切関係がありません。」 is a very common phrase, which you could consider tweaking for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry I have to change my previous answer completely, since I am sorry I missed your comment on your comment line,

> The message I'd like to convey is that **the speaker was not hired by X company** to produce the derivative work, and **is not employed at that company. :)**

Then my personal recommendation would be ( although I have to think still what kind of work the derivative work" is exactly, )

> これはX社{しゃ}から依頼{いらい}されたものです。ただし私{わたくし}はX社{しゃ}とは何{なん}ら雇用上{こようじょう}の関係{かんけい}も御座{ござ}いません。

Kindly be reminded **雇用上{こようじょう}の関係{かんけい}** means

> Somebody is being employed by the **** company now

I am sorry.

Thank you.

Comment: Again thank you for your effort for editting. Sincerely.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! It was perfect. 勉強になりました！

Comment: Could someone let me know how I can place rubis above Kanjis...

Comment: @KentaroTomono place braces {} around the furigana. Similar to how you had it before, but with the {} braces instead of the parentheses ().